# How to plot multiple curves on same plot in julia?

Tags: julia

I am using **julia** to build **linear regression model** from scratch. After having done all my mathematical calculations, I need to plot a **linear regression graph**

I have a **scatter plot** and **linear fit** (Linear line) plots separately ready, How do I combine them or use my linear fit plot on scatter plot?

Basically, how do I draw multiple plots on a single plot in **Julia**?

Note: Neither do I know python or R

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,3,4,5,6]

plot1 = scatter(x,y)
plot2 = plot(x,y)  #line plot

#plot3 = plot1+plot2 (how?)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia doesn't come with one built-in plotting package, so you need to choose one. Popular plotting packages are Plots, Gadfly, PyPlot, GR, PlotlyJS and others. You need to install them first, and with Plots you'll also need to install a "backend" package (e.g. one of the last three mentioned above).

With Plots, e.g., you'd do

```
using Plots; gr() # if GR is the plotting "backend" you've chosen
scatter(point_xs, point_ys) # the points
plot!(line_xs, line_ys)     # the line
```

The key here is the `plot!` command (as opposed to `plot`), which modifies an existing plot rather than creating a new one.

More simply you can do

```
scatter(x,y, smooth = true) # fits the trendline automatically
```

See also http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/

(disclaimer: I'm associated with Plots - others may give you different advice)

Comment: using Plots

a = plot(f,0,10)


plot!(a,scatter(Tv,Sales))

when do this, I get error

Comment: Moreover, I don't want to Julia to automatically find and fit the trend line.
I have found the trend line and now wish to plot that trend line on a scatter plot

Comment: That syntax is not the syntax I gave you in my answer, and it is not correct. If you update your post with some data for the scatter points and the line I can show you the correct syntax.

Comment: Look, I have updated my post with sample code, is that fine? if yes, can you show  me how do I achieve this task

Comment: You can't combine the plots into a single plot after creating them. You'd either do `scatter(x,y); plot!(x,y)` (which will work). In your example, you CAN do `plot3 = plot(plot1, plot2)` with Plots, but that will create a plot with two subplots.